# Confusion about vectors representing spins or other things in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory

I am sorry if my language makes not too much sense, I am a little confused about the meaning of everything at this point. Let us say I have two vectors of dimension 4 in a complex vector (Hilbert) space. The first one represents the state of a 3/2 spin, and the second the state (tensor product) of 2 1/2 spins. They transform under 3D rotations in different ways.

1. Do they belong to the same vector space? What is it different about them in more formal terms?
2. How many other “kinds” of 4D vectors could exist that transform in different ways under rotations?

My guess is that these two exhaust all possibilities as one transforms as an irreducible representation of the group of rotations and the other one under a reducible one. Does this exhaust all possible kinds of 4D “objects” (vectors)? Is it the same for an $N$ dimensional object? In the sense that it has to transform under 3D rotations either by an irreducible representation or by a sum of irreducible representations? Is every finite dimensional vector in $H$ related in some way to spins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Do they belong to the same vector space? What is it different about them in more formal terms?

No. These questions are *all* put to rest in a half-decent introduction to QM angular momentum. For an irreducible representation, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the dimensionality of the representation, *2s+1*, and its spin, *s*. So your first 4-spinor with spin 3/2 transforms infinitesimally by the 4×4   matrices $\vec S $ and its eigenvalue under $\vec S \cdot \vec S $ is always $3/2(3/2+1)=15/4$.

Your second 4-spinor,$1/2\otimes 1/2$, transforms under the likewise 4×4 matrices
$\vec S \otimes {\mathbb I}+{\mathbb I}\otimes\vec S $, (with the $S$s and ${\mathbb I}$s being 2×2 matrices) which, however, are reducible, ie, they act very differently on a 3D block subspace (spin 1), and a 1D block (trivially, in this particular case: a singlet). The eigenvalues of each block  under $\vec S \cdot \vec S$ are different, *1(1+1)=2* and 0, respectively. So, at your level, the fact the two dimensionalities are the same is a coincidence of apples and oranges.

> 2.How many other “kinds” of 4D vectors could exist that transform in different ways under rotations?
> My guess is that these two exhaust all possibilities as one transforms as an irreducible representation of the group of rotations and the other one under a reducible one. Does this exhaust all possible kinds of 4D “objects” (vectors)?

Well, you may juxtapose two different spin 1/2 in a direct sum, $1/2\oplus 1/2$, acted upon by $\vec S \oplus \vec S$, or consider $0\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0$, but basically you are done.

> Is it the same for an -dimensional object? In the sense that it has to transform under 3D rotations either by an irreducible representation or by a sum of irreducible representations?

By now you must have seen how dimensionality is not as significant as you appeared to believe, and  you may find an infinity of such coincidences for higher irreducible and reducible representations, but there isn't much for you to focus on, beyond sudoku entertainment. For instance, a spin 7/2 irrep acts on an 8D spinor, just as the unrelated reducible $(1/2)^{\otimes 3}$ does...

> Is every finite-dimensional vector in  related in some way to spins?

If you are restricting yourself to  spin  operators, yes, but there are other, more significant,  parts of QM, of course,  and their corresponding Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Great, thanks. But rotations are always generated by angular momentum operators, righ? so, any N dimensional degree of freedom, regardless of being spin or something else, will transform in the same way as a N dimensional spinor, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. There are all kinds of representation matrices, irreducible or not, describing these rotations. The operators acting on Hilbert space may remind you of an NxN rotation matrix....